# C header using BOOL functions

Tags: c, header, boolean

How can a bool function be added in a header? I've tried this so far and doesn't work

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_H_
#define FUNCTION_H_

BOOL MyFunction();

#endif
```

Comment: `#define "doesn't work"` :P

Comment: Don't use some homebrew boolean constants or types. C has a built-in boolena type and a header for the constants. See `stdbool.h`. And don't use K&R syntax for function declarations. Use correct prototypes.

Comment: should not have overlayed the original question text.  rather add any new/changed text as additional text with a prefix like `EDIT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_H_
#define FUNCTION_H_

BOOL MyFunction();

#endif
```

will, as you have found out, not compile.

Instead use:

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_H_
#define FUNCTION_H_

#include <stdbool.h>

bool MyFunction( void );

#endif
```